# Classpath error for .data file for WEKA

Tags: java, classpath, weka

I am trying some simple code with weka API for Java. While trying to find numberofAttributes it fires error for any .data file. While it works fine with .arff files.
have downloaded the files from [UCI repo](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases)

```
---Registering Weka Editors---
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): jdbc.idbDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): com.mckoi.JDBCDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
java.io.IOException: premature end of line. Expected attribute type., read Token[EOL], line 5
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.errms(ConverterUtils.java:912)
    at weka.core.converters.C45Loader.readHeader(C45Loader.java:417)
    at weka.core.converters.C45Loader.getStructure(C45Loader.java:211)
    at weka.core.converters.C45Loader.getDataSet(C45Loader.java:234)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils$DataSource.getDataSet(ConverterUtils.java:268)
    at MetaFeatureStatistical.main(MetaFeatureStatistical.java:42)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MetaFeatureStatistical.main(MetaFeatureStatistical.java:43)
```

line number 42 and 43 are as following:

```
instances=source.getDataSet(); 
instances.setClassIndex(instances.numAttributes()-1);
```

Comment: It seems there is some kind of problem with your jdbc installation and its coupling with your weka project.

Comment: @mostruash havnt added any JDBC jars neither do I need it. simple data files lying in a folder that I'm trying to access

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error at `instances.numAttributes()` because instances is null. `source.getDataSet()` cannot complete, thus instances is not assigned a value, because there is a problem with the file, probably in line 5. We can't say why until we know the file that you are using.

Comment: this is the file 
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/

iris.data i'm using. .names is there in the folder as well. 

I got that it's null but why only with it fails to load only .data is something i'm nt getting

Comment: Because the fifth column is of type nominal, others are numbers. For nominal types, the header must state which pre-defined values a nominal type can take.E.g.: it can take Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolour or Iris-virginica.

Comment: cn u plz tell me the exact modification to the file

Comment: can't I use .data files without converting it to .arff ?

Comment: Actually they is no difference between your .data files and .arff files except that you need those directives which start with '@' in your file, as explained in the link above. Other than that, you split your data with new lines and commas etc.